# Пишутся в файл байты вместо текста

Tags: python, python-2.x, unicode, кодировка, python-2.7

У меня есть словарь со строками, который я дамплю в *json*, а затем в файл. Никак не могу разобраться, как сделать на *python2.7* так, чтобы в *json* были русские символы (*utf-8*), а не байты. Для простоты и воспроизводимости буду всё писать на *stdout*. Делаю так:

```
full_text = u'«Комсомолка» расспросила экспертов, насколько это серьезно и к чему готовиться России'
dict_for_write = {
    u'full_text': full_text
}
print json.dumps(dict_for_write, encoding=u'utf-8')
```

> "full_text":  u'\xab\u041a\u043e\u043c\u0441\u043e\u043c\u043e\u043b\u043a\u0430\xbb \u0440\u0430\u0441\u0441\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0438\u043b\u0430 \u044d\u043a\u0441\u043f\u0435\u0440\u0442\u043e\u0432, \u043d\u0430\u0441\u043a\u043e\u043b\u044c\u043a\u043e \u044d\u0442\u043e \u0441\u0435\u0440\u044c\u0435\u0437\u043d\u043e \u0438 \u043a \u0447\u0435\u043c\u0443 \u0433\u043e\u0442\u043e\u0432\u0438\u0442\u044c\u0441\u044f \u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0438'

P.s. Если данные писать в файл, то пробовал открывать файл для записи в *utf-8*:

```
file = codecs.open(path, u'w', u'utf-8')
```

Как победить эту проблему?